# HTTP calls with application/x-www-form-urlencoded not working in android build for an angular ionic project with capacitor

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am creating an application in angular 15 with ionic 6 and capacitor 4. I have to make a application/x-www-form-urlencoded api call inside of my application which for some reason is not working. When I inspect the application in chrome inspect, it shows me error saying `API can't be used because it is not implemented for current platform`. I tried using axios, capacitorHTTP but did not work. Capacitor HTTP brought in errors of its own like `error: cannot find symbol import com.getcapacitor.PluginRequestCodes`
I created another app like this with axios calls but since they exchange data as JSON format, they work fine but not this app. Please help, thank you

I have tried setting my params as a string, URLSearchParams that i convert to string.
I have tried axios, capacitor HTTP but did not work.